# pygame.display.set_mode fill entire screen

Tags: python, pygame, screen-size

When writing Pygame programs it has always bugged me that if someone else has a screen smaller or larger than mine It wont work correctly. when I use:

```
pygame.display.set_mode([1680, 1000]),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                             /\
                        My screen size
```

It fills my screen but on a different screen size I would need to use a different resolution.
Is there a way to set the resolution as 100 percent of the screeen

Answer (score 0):

[pygame.display.list_modes](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.list_modes) give you available resolutions so you can choose the best resolution.

Answer (score -1):

`pygame.display.set_mode(0,0)`

should fill the screen.